# Count total id wise, id passes in IN clause but if no record of that id must return 0

Tags: mysql

I have my sql query which works perfect but I need to make some changes to get exactly result what I want

my query

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS total
FROM element_clicks
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23)
AND (DATE_FORMAT(`created_on`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-11-15' AND '2018-12-14') 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ;
```

It's give result

```
1 --> 10
4 --> 12
23 --> 100
```

But I want something like below

```
1 --> 10 
2 --> 0 
3 --> 0 
4 --> 12
5 --> 0 
6 --> 0 
7 --> 0 
8 --> 0 
9 --> 0 
10 --> 0 
11 --> 0 
12 --> 0 
13 --> 0 
14 --> 0 
15 --> 0 
16 --> 0 
17 --> 0 
18 --> 0 
19 --> 0 
20 --> 0 
23 --> 100
```

Comment: Please Show your table

Comment: I don't know stack overflow give me. they also give me some more icon to 
see this link http://prntscr.com/lusguj

Comment: @madforstrength my table has only one column it has the value 1,2,3,1,3,4,23,10 and date. you omit date in your answer

Comment: How do you select `section_id` but group by `id`? Can you please show the table structure?

Comment: ohh sorry I made mistake in my query now you see it is correct

Comment: @lucumt this explains how to get them: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use IN for obtain a relation but you could a table eg: create by union

```
SELECT  e.section_id
    , COUNT(e.section_id) AS total  
FROM ( 
    select 1 as id
    union 
    select 2
    ....
    union
    select 23

) t  
left join element_clicks e on e.id = t.id
    AND (DATE_FORMAT(e.`created_on`,'%Y-%m-%d') 
            BETWEEN '2018-11-15' AND '2018-12-14') 
GROUP BY t.id 
ORDER BY t.id ;
```

or you can create a temporary table an join

Comment: In MySQL you don't need `from dual`

Comment: @Nick   .. thanks  .. answer  updated with your suggestion